# Knockout "if" and "ifnot" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using knockout and have this code

```
self.array = ko.observableArray([]);
```

HTML

```
<!--ko if: array().length > 0-->
<tr>
<td>Some text</td>
</tr>
<!--/ko-->
<!--ko ifnot: array().length > 0-->
<tr>
<td>Some other text</td>
</tr>
<!--/ko-->
```

I'm using some other knockout statements and they works but this doesn't work, and I can't figure out why. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't very helpful. what errors are you seeing?

Comment: I don't get any error in console, simply doesn't work. I don't get any of those texts in any case. Don't know other way to debug because it's HTML.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that using virtual elements inside a table requires the use of a wrapping `<tbody>` element.

See my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yq9v7d0g/2/

Once I added the `<tbody>` element, everything worked fine. This used to be a problem in Internet Explorer, but seems to be an issue again.

Comment: Quite strange. That also happens in Chrome.However it works in FF

Comment: I forgot to write here table and tbody tags but I have them, and my case looks exactly you made example on jsfiddle. :(

Comment: What I have worked on chrome. What version of knockout are you using? I was using the latest (3.x) in my fiddle